# delete multiple rows from database depending on which checkboxes are checked using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a code for users to unsubscribe to the various alerts they subscribed.I thought of doing it by maintaining session once they login, and by checking their userid.
I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hgd");
echo "<html><body>";

if (!$con)
    {
    die("could not connect" . mysql . error());
    }

mysql_select_db("Project", $con);

if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) || isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    echo "Unsubscribe for alerts on:" . "<br/>";
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $query = "select * from BOOK_ALERTS where Userid='$userid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $isbn = $row[1];
        $datapoint = $row[2];
        $type = $row[4];
        $value = $row[3];
        $time = $row[7];
        $str = "A book with ISBN:" . $isbn . " whose " . $datapoint . "'s " . $type . " " . $value;
        echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $str . "'/>$str<br />";
        }

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='UNSUBSCRIBE'>";
    echo "</form>";
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
            {
            $delquery = "delete  from BOOK_ALERTS where Isbn='$isbn' AND Datapoint='$datapoint' AND     Alert_type='$type' AND Datapoint_value='$value'";
            $delresult = mysql_query($delquery, $con);
            if (!$delresult)
                {
                echo "Deleting record failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
                }
              else
                {
                echo "Unsubscribed the alert for " . $str;
                }
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<br />";
        echo "already logged in";
        header("Location:./abc.php");
        }

    echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

The above code deletes only the last row no matter which checkbox is checked because the delete query deletes that row which takes the value of the variables when lastly updated. 
I dont know any other way to write this code.Can anyone please help?

Comment: The main problem is that you are not evaluating the actual $_POST values (you are just checking if they are set, but not using them). Instead you are evaluating the variables you used to display the checkboxes, which is why (only) the last one gets deleted. (see my answer for more details)

Comment: Also consider NOT editing your question source code (adapting it to an answer), since this makes it hard to follow the problems Question & Answer style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the value part of the checkbox for an id instead of the user readable string (or if not available maybe the ISBN). Value will NOT be shown to the user but the values of all the checked checkboxes (with the same name tag) will end up in an array when processing the input, eg:

If `row[0]` is your id:

```
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $row[0] . "'/>$str<br />";
```

Also right now you are not evaluating what the user has checked but instead using the last `$value` which you have **displayed** for deletion.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && is_array($_POST['checkbox']))
foreach ( $_POST['checkbox'] as $checked_id )
{
    // $delquery = "select * from BOOK_ALERTS where Isbn='$isbn' AND Datapoint='$datapoint' AND     Alert_type='$type' AND Datapoint_value='$value'";
    $delquery = "DELETE FROM BOOK_ALERTS WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($checked_id);
    $delresult = mysql_query($delquery, $con);
    if (!$delresult)
    {
        echo "Deleting record failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Unsubscribed the alert with id " . intval($checked_id); // Also this is not really nice showing a number to your user, you might wanna modify it later, but I really don't wanna throw too much at you at once
    }
}
```

This loops over every checked checkbox (checking before that it IS in fact an array).

You also previously did not use a `DELETE` statement but `SELECT`, which only retrieves data but does not remove it.

As you can see this relies on a single ID for each record, which I can only recommend in your case.

Furthermore you will NEED to escape your data before inserting it into the database (as I did here), google for **sql injection** for more information.

**Edit:** This code does delete every CHECKED record, you will have to switch that around, if you need it the other way.

Comment: It is Delete and not select.That was unintentional. Am new to PHP, what do i initialiZe to $checked_id? When i edited my code with the changes u gave, i got the following error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /var/www/unsubisbn.php on line 32

Comment: Do you have an ID field in your BOOK_ALERTS table (usually with the attributes 'AUTO_INCREMENT 'and 'PRIMARY KEY')? This would make life for you a lot easier, or with other words, working with a specific row.

Comment: missed a bracket, that was my mistake, I fix the code right away!

Comment: i dont have any autoincrement field in the table.

Comment: |
desc of table:
 Userid            int(11)      NO    PRI   NULL 
 Isbn              varchar(30)  NO    PRI | NULL    
 Datapoint         varchar(40)  NO    PRI | NULL 
 Datapoint_value   float        NO    PRI | NULL  
 Alert_type      | varchar(30)  NO    PRI | NULL   
 
Each user can subscribe for same isbn with different Values.

Comment: Then I would add one, execute following: `ALTER TABLE \`BOOK_ALERTS\` ADD  \`AlertId\` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST`

Comment: I did that! So do i assign $checked_id=$id and the value of checkbox to $id where $id=$row[0]??

Comment: But be aware that this changes the index of your other fields (since it will be inserted as first field), for example your UserId is now $row[1] no longer $row[0]

Comment: $checked_id will be "automatically" assigned to every checked checkbox by `foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checked_id)`. For every checkbox that has been clicked, this loop will be passed once, and $checked_id has the value of its id.

Comment: This is the error i keep getting for the foreach statement: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /var/www/unsubisbn.php on line 33

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && is_array($_POST['checkbox']
foreach ( $_POST['checkbox'] as $checked_id )
{

Comment: The code posted is fine, there was an `)` missing before, but that was fixed a while ago ... but according to your error you removed the second bracket as well, instead of adding one! It should be `... && is_array($_POST['checkbox'])) foreach ...` not `... && is_array($_POST['checkbox'] foreach ...`! See above.

Comment: Yeah!This helped!Thanks!But once i check the box and press the delete button,it gets deleted from the database but it doesnt disappear from the list i print on the screen with checkboxes. Any remedy for that?

Comment: This is because after the submit, you are printing the list first, and only then delete the entries. If you put your whole `if (isset($_POST['checkbox']) ...` block as first thing in your `if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) || isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {` area, it should delete it first, and by that print it correct right after submission. (But the notifications like "Unsubscribed the alert with id..." will also be on top this way)